# Controlling pivot chart filters using custom built slicers data

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, dax

I have a data set in my excel power pivot in the below format

```
Week  Value
Wk15  10
Wk16  12
Wk17  20
Wk18  8
Wk19  50
Wk20  5
```

I would like to create a pivot chart in excel with Week as dimension and Sum(Value) as a measure. That is the easy part.

But now, I would need to have a custom slicer with values like

```
"Last 2 weeks"
"Last 4 weeks"
```

and selecting them should restrict my pivot chart's dimension to the corresponding values only.

Say, if my pivot chart is a column chart, and it initially displays 6 bars for all 6 values, then selecting "Last 2 weeks" from the slicer should restrict it to only the latest 2 weeks data(consider current week is wk20, then only wk19 and wk20 should be displayed). i.e only 2 bars.

How can I do this without using any macro? Can any one explain it please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

something similar to what you are asking can be done directly in the PivotTable, with PivotFields containing Date data type, unfortunately it cannot be done using Slicers, neither from the PivotChart.
Additionally your request is kind of complicated as the choices you would like to have are not exclusive, as they intersects with each other, i.e.: “Last 4 weeks” includes “Last 2 Weeks”.
The way this is done in the Autofilter and PivotFilters is using XlDynamicFilterCriteria. Nevertheles, your requirement can be achieved with some small modifications:

1.Adding a a DataValidation cell in the worksheet with the following list:

*“0.All,1.This Week,2 Last Weeks,3 Last Weeks,4 Last Weeks”*

To allow the user selection of the customized view

2.Adding a “Name” range at worksheet level for the DataValidation cell named *“kWeekSelection”* Allows the use of selected view to update the data

3.Adding a WeekSelection Field (column) to your data named *“!WkSel”* with the following formula:

*=IF(LEFT('WeeksChart'!kWeekSelection)=0,"All",
IF(AND($C9<=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY()),
$C9>=SUM(1,-LEFT(' WeeksChart'!kWeekSelection),ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY()))),"Wk.Sel","N/A"))*

This formula allows the use of this field as a kind of dynamic filter. It assumes the name of the worksheet holding the PivotChart is “WeeksChart”

4.Adding the field “!WkSel” to the Filters section of the PivotTable

*How it works:* After choosing the view option from the DataValidation, press {F9} to calculate the workbook, *(it’s advised to use calculation manual)*, then refresh data either from the PivotTable or the PivotChart

The view “0.All” allows to use the other fields to filter the PivotTable and PivotChart with something different than the customized views.

*Nevertheless, be aware that this is not the most efficient manner of generating these pivottable\pivotchart views, the use of macros can greatly increase the stability, efficiency and confidence of the outcome.*

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not possible, especially not without any macros. If you have your data grouped by week, insert a slicer for the week column.

The idea with slicers is that you can use Shift-Click to select the weeks to include in the pivot, instead of having an endless array of pre-defined possibilities like "last 2", "last 3", "last 4" etc.